# Changing Display Resolution of Surface Pro 3 when Docked/Undocked

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, scaling, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I recently got a Surface Pro 3 for work.  I have it connected with two external monitors and and using the Surface in the dock as a third monitor.

The monitors are set for 1920x1080 and text is scaled at 100%.  If I try to use max resolution (2160x1440) on the Surface, everything comes out much too small.  In order to compensate, the Surface is set for 1280x800.

When I undock the surface and take it with me, the resolution automatically changes to 2160x1440 and the text remains scaled at 100%.  Unfortunately, this makes it near impossible to use, and requires me to manually change the settings each time I undock the computer, and to change them back each time I redock.

It is cumbersome to change the setting each time I pull the Surface from the dock and defeats the purpose of it being a mobile device.  There has to be a better way.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of multi-monitor Windows!

This is a constant problem when you have high-res screens.

What you can do is to slightly change the scaling on the surface screen only. But it is hit and miss.

The other thing that sometimes helps is to reboot after changing screen configurations. The SP Pro 3 seems to have a bit of a mind of its own when it comes to resolutions. Thankfully, restarting the surface is a quick process.

Comment: How do you change the scaling on the Surface only?  In the "Make text and other items larger or smaller" menu, it will only let me scale text for all screens at once.  It's an all or nothing proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution issues when docking and undocking is a serious shortcoming in the surface pro 3, or is it windows 8? I am running a single external monitor (2560 x 1440) via the docking station and outputting to the external monitor only. So a simple set up.  The ONLY solution (to accurately render the screen in the correct resolution) is to reboot the surface pro 3 when its docked and again when its undocked!  Obviously re-booting is not acceptable and defeats the point of being mobile!

If you use the pro 3 on its own and make the text larger or smaller it requires a reboot or log off/on. This indicates its not a simple fix.

So far this is the only pro 3 issue I have found. Windows 10 is out soon, maybe that will fix it...

Comment: This doesn't really present a solution to the problem in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of Windows 10 Anniversary Edition, this serious issue still remains.